# Blender how to install builds

Tags: installation, versions

Hi I have a Windows 10 and have Blender 2.78c installed on my computer but just recently downloaded blender -2.780-git.a372638 build dated for 8/1/2017. After I extract the file I don't see an installer or setup executable. How does a person use the builds for Blender?

Comment: could you please add the link of the page where you got that "build"? could it be a source release? usually windows binary (compiled) releases are in a .zip archive and have a blender.exe ready to launch...

Comment: Here is the link https://builder.blender.org/download/blender-2.78-a372638-win32.zip

Comment: Whoops hit the wrong key. But this is that link I am talking about but the 64 bit instead.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research I discovered that the Blender builds don't have a install file but instead they just have the Blender symbol which is called "Application" with just a click a person can open Blender. I was used to running a set up install file which would load in the program. I just downloaded Blender 2.79 and after extracting the download just clicked on the Blender Icon and the program starts up the application.